# System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object Line no 82

Tags: apex

How to remove this error

```
public class cls_QuotePDFExtentionController12
{

    public list<Enquiry_Product__c> lstEnqProduct{get;set;}

    public list<wrappedCls> lstOfAnything{get;set;}

    public Id quoteId{get;set;}

    public decimal subtotal=0.0;
    Public Decimal Amount{get;set;}
    Public Decimal TotalNetvalue{get;set;}

    public synthesis_Quote__c listeq{get;set;}
    public List<Enquiry_Accessory__c> eacc{get;set;}
    Public List<Enquiry_Accessory__c> ac{get;set;}
    public integer a{get;set;}
    public string code{get;set;}
    public list<double> lis{get;set;}
    public String quoteTab{get;set;}
    public integer pno{get;set;}
    public double ano{get;set;}
    public synthesis_Quote__c Enqid{get;set;}
    public cls_QuotePDFExtentionController12(){

    }

    public cls_QuotePDFExtentionController12(ApexPages.StandardController 
                                             controller) 
    {
        a=0;
        TotalNetvalue=0.0;
        lstEnqProduct =new List<Enquiry_Product__c>();
        quoteId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');

        Enqid = [ Select 
                 Id,synthesis_Quote__c.Note1__c,synthesis_Quote__c.Note2__c, 
                 synthesis_Quote__c.Note3__c,



                 synthesis_Quote__c.Note4__c,synthesis_Quote__c.Note5__c,Name,Enquiry_Name__c 
                 From synthesis_Quote__c Where id =: quoteId];

        Enquiry__c Enq = [Select ID,Name From Enquiry__c Where id 
                          =:Enqid.Enquiry_Name__c];

        List<Enquiry_Accessory__c> eacc = [Select ID ,Name,Accessory__c From 
                                           Enquiry_Accessory__c Where Enquiry_Product__r.Enquiry__r.Id =: enq.id AND  

                                           Enquiry_Product__r.Product_Name__c=Null];

        Set<id> ids = New Set<id>();

        For(Enquiry_Accessory__c e : eacc){

            ids.add(e.Accessory__c);


        }



    }

    public list<wrappedCls> getWithAnything1(){

        try
        {
            listeq=[select Enquiry_Name__c from synthesis_Quote__c where 
                    id=:quoteId];
        }
        catch(Exception E)
        {
        }
        Amount =0.0;
        lstEnqProduct = [select id,Quantity__c,Enquiry_Product_info_for_Quote__c,Model_No__c,
                         Product_and_model__c,Product_Name__c,Product__r.name,Total_Price__c,Product__r.Product_Description__c,
                         (select id,Accessory__r.Description__c, Accessory_Name__c,Quantity__c,Total_Price__c,Sales_Price__c,Display_Price__c,Discount__c,Unit_Price__c,
                          Complementary__c from Enquiry_Accessories__r 
                         ),Sales_Price__c,Unit_Price__c,Discount__c,Total_Cost_of_Product_with_Accessories1__c  
                         from Enquiry_Product__c where Enquiry__c =:listeq.Enquiry_name__c  And name!=null order by name ASC]; 


        for(Enquiry_Product__c pp:lstEnqProduct ){
            pno=1;
            ano=0;
            //only Accessories

            if(pp.Product__c==null && pp.Enquiry_Accessories__r.size()>0){
                for(Enquiry_Accessory__c cc:pp.Enquiry_Accessories__r ){
                    system.debug('@@@@@@@@@@@@@@Saurabh'+cc);
                    lstOfAnything.add(new wrappedCls(cc,pno));
                    system.debug('@@@@@@@@@@@@@@Suman'+lstOfAnything.size());
                    pno++;
                }

            }

            // Only product
            if(pp.Product__c!=null && pp.Enquiry_Accessories__r.size()==0){

                lstOfAnything.add(new wrappedCls(pp,pno));
                system.debug('@@@@@@@@@@@@@@Pankaj'+pp);
                pno++;
            }
            // product with accessories
            if(pp.Product__c!=null && pp.Enquiry_Accessories__r.size()>0){
                double pa=0.0+pno;
                lstOfAnything.add(new wrappedCls(pp,pno));
                for(Enquiry_Accessory__c dd:pp.Enquiry_Accessories__r ){

                    lstOfAnything.add(new wrappedCls(dd,pa));

                    pa=pa+0.1;

                }
            }

        }



        return lstOfAnything;
    }
    public class wrappedCls{
        public Enquiry_Product__c ep{get;set;}
        public Enquiry_Accessory__c  ea{get;set;}
        public Enquiry_Accessory__c  ea1{get;set;}
        public integer countp{get;set;}
        public integer countpa{get;set;}
        public double countpac{get;set;}
        public wrappedCls(Enquiry_Product__c xx, integer countp1 ){
            ep=xx;
            countp=countp1;
        }
        public wrappedCls(Enquiry_Accessory__c  yy,integer counta1){

            ea=yy;
            countpa=counta1;
        }
        public wrappedCls(Enquiry_Accessory__c  pa1,double countpac1){
            ea=pa1;
            countpac=countpac1;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is an unreadable mess due to your formatting, and you've included way too much code. People will be more likely to help if you pull out just the lines around your error, including where you populate the variables involved, and ask a specific question. The error itself tells you the problem: you're trying to read a property from or call a method on an object that is `null`.

Comment: 'lstOfAnything' code is saying that this list is getting deferenced to null 
null pointer exception I m getting......

Answer (score 1):

Your problem actually comes from a higher line in the code; if quoteId is null, then you'll get the null pointer exception later, since listeq is null. Instead, you need to abort early:

```
if(quoteId == null) {
  return;
}
listeq=[select Enquiry_Name__c from synthesis_Quote__c where id=:quoteId];
```

You should not arbitrarily put try-catch blocks in your code that do not show an error, because it will make your code harder to debug (as you've literally just discovered).

Comment: quoteId is not null I have checked in debug logs,
its giving the exact id what I want.....
Even my query list is giving me exact list of values what I want but there is only one problem when I am the value to wrapper list then list is getting null

Comment: @RKP Then maybe you have the wrong ID type, or the user can't query the record... no clue, but line 82 only has one possible null pointer exception. Unfortunately, the previous line is still causing an error because there's no data returned.

Comment: Got the soltion for it long time back. This List 'lstOfAnything' was not initialized.